# OpenShift with Laravel displaying sensitive data on debug mode

Tags: openshift-online-2

I'm having Laravel on debug mode in Openshift. But the information printed out sensitive data like:

```
REDIRECT_OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD    XXXXXXXXXXXXX
REDIRECT_OPENSHIFT_CLOUD_DOMAIN     XXXXXXXXXXX
REDIRECT_OPENSHIFT_APP_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY   XXXXXXXXXXX
REDIRECT_PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I have 2 question here.

1. Where did Laravel retrieve these sensitive data from?
2. How can I disable these data be printed out?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel likely retrieved these from the environment associated environment variables located within your OpenShift Gear. In order to keep this information from being displayed you'll likely have to alter the way Laravel displays its information in debug mode. Check out http://laravel.com/docs/errors for more information.